# Workbench Moderation - Admin Preview - Show Current Revision in Front-End

Tags: workbench

Can someone please help me on the following use case related to workbench module showing current revision but in the front-end.

**What I need:**

When we hit the preview button on edit content type (editorial) form, I need a LIVE PREVIEW, to show the current version edited, using my front-end theme I've, to show the article details. I don't want the default preview of Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want [Page Preview](https://www.drupal.org/project/pagepreview).

> **Page Preview** is a low-impact alternative to Drupal's core node preview
>   functionality.
>
> **Why would I need this?**
>
> Drupal's regular node add/edit form provides a "Preview" button that
>   allows you to see what your node content will look like after all of
>   the input filters are applied, without having to first save the node.
>   However, it doesn't allow you to see what the entire node will look
>   like within the context of a fully rendered page

Comment: thank you shawn, but our team tried with page preview and it is not serving our purpose, as it still renders the view in Iframe in admin and not showing the front end view fully loaded.

any further guidance please?

Comment: Your question is very scant on criteria, but there's also another, heavier, solution called [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey).